# Who makes non-white iPhone earbuds similar in function and design to Apple's default earbuds?

Tags: iphone, hardware-recommendation, accessories

I like the default iPhone earbuds, but I'd prefer a color other than white, which is the only color Apple makes them. Are there any other good earbuds that have the following characteristics?

- Have all the iPhone-specific controls
- Are earphones/earbuds, i.e. do not go inside the ear canal (since those are uncomfortable and always pop out of my ear)

Comment: This might be difficult to answer depending on your location. I got mine at a local Apple reseller and I've seen earbuds with iPhone controls in several electronic stores around here. Don't expect too much in term of audio quality though.

Answer (score 0):

I've bought a couple of [Belkin Headphones Adapter with Remote](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002K4GBEI)s, one because a few of them tore, and two because I bought one for myself and my girlfriend for use in our own cars'.

It's a very simple gadget. Push the middle for play/pause/skip/previous, and it has volume up/down controls on the extremities. Note that you have to plug the adapter into the phone, it cannot be the other way around.

These have worked in an iPhone, iPad, and iPod, and they're chiefly designed for the buttonless iPod shuffle, but work with everything else.

If you don't need the mic, you could get by with this, and any pair of headphones you want.

Comment: Note also that more and more headphones are generally beginning to include "Apple-controls", because many smart phones and portable players support them nowadays, in at least a basic manner.

Answer (score 0):

This question is so subjective you're better off getting some shopping advice in the store. You probably want to make the comparison yourself, factoring in price, quality and features.

Personally I do like the Bose MIE2i a lot. They have volume controls and a play/pause/accept call button, and they feel very comfortable (they go slightly in the ear canal, but not in an irritating way) and stay well into place, even when jogging. The sounds is also a lot better compared to the previous iteration of the Bose earbuds, with richer mid-tones and highs, next to the full bass.

Then again, that was just my personal opinion, so go do some shopping and compare!